# Opened applications log

Tags: applications

Is there any way, such as an application or a terminal command, to display a log of every application that has been running on the computer? A bit like a keylogger, but for applications instead of keyboard. I did not find anything on the internet.

If it does not exist, do you think that programming such a tool would be possible?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an application called [Time Sink](https://manytricks.com/timesink/) ($5, free trial available) which can track time spent in an application in the foreground. I believe it also tracks background time too.

For a native and more techy solution, you can run this terminal command:

```
top -d 5 -b > /var/log/top.txt
```

This command will run top every 5 seconds as defined by -d, -b is for batch mode and this is used for sending output to a file. You wouldn't want to have this running all the time unless you're compressing the log file or using logrotate, as the log file would get large.

Comment: Thank you ! What is logrotate? Is it better to use it or to compress the file? And how to compress it automatically?

Comment: @MarinD Logrotate is a unix utility program used to, well, [rotate logs](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/understanding-logrotate-utility/). :) It can also handle automatic compression of old files. Rackspace has a [good support page](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/sample-logrotate-configuration-and-troubleshooting/) showing sample configurations.